# Strange space between divs in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I've got a strange space between two divs on my new website, using chrome.

Check it out: http://www.predatordesign.de/temp2

Screenshot: [image]

CSS for this section:

```
.background-arrow {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 20px;
        background: url(../img/background-arrow.svg) center bottom no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        z-index: 10;
    }
```

Comment: Are you referring to the horizontal line below the triangle? I'm not seeing it in Chrome. Please post a complete code example in your question so that we can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is scaling issue. Change bottom coordinate of your polygon from 20 to 21.

After edits SVG has to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 18.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Ebene_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 2920 20" enable-background="new 0 0 2920 20" xml:space="preserve">
<polygon fill="#333333" points="0,21 0,0 1445.5,0 1460,17 1474.5,0 2920,0 2920,21 "/>
</svg>
```